# JAVA - Regular Expressions : Unclosed Character Class

Tags: java, regex

The following is throwing an exception:

```
Pattern.matches(""+input.charAt(i),"\\s");
```

---

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
Unclosed character class near index 0.
```

I don't understand why. Does the text I am matching against also need to have escaped characters?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIqTy.png) of workspace in case it helps.

Comment: maybee Use: (?:\\t\\n) instead of the brickets

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the parameters in the right order for what you want to do?

Comment: You probably should have checked the API first as if you did, you'd see in an instance what was wrong.

Comment: Sorry I just started using Java recently. Do you mean I should have checked the javadoc for Regex's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the parameters in the wrong order (from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29))

```
Pattern.matches(String regex, CharSequence input)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using it seems wrong.
You should do

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[ \\t\\n]");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(""+input.charAt(i));
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

**[From the reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a special class for whitespaces. You code can be simplified to:

```
Pattern.matches("\\s", <your_input>);
```

Comment: Hi, Yes. I made that change but I am still getting an exception. I am guessing it has to do with the scanner I am using? (It is in the screenshot).

Comment: @MarcoSalazar I've updated the answer. It seems that you put arguments in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be

```
Pattern.matches("\\s",String.valueOf(input.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Better break it up this way....

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Your_Source_String");
```